# mysql query output projector and whiteboard

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct

I've got this small assignment:
Find those rooms that have projectors, but not whiteboards.

```
CREATE TABLE Equipment 
(
room VARCHAR(15),
type VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO Equipment VALUES ('Dreyer-201','projector');
INSERT INTO Equipment VALUES **('Zuse-127','projector');**
INSERT INTO Equipment VALUES ('Shannon-164','projector');
INSERT INTO Equipment VALUES ('Dreyer-201','whiteboard');
INSERT INTO Equipment VALUES **('Zuse-127','whiteboard');**
INSERT INTO Equipment VALUES ('Shannon-164','whiteboard');
```

This is my answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT room, type
FROM Equipment
WHERE type = 'projector' AND NOT type = 'whiteboard'
```

And it is working - but my output lists the room Zuse-127. I know it stands alone with both projector and whiteboard, but how can I fix this problem? So the room Zuse-127 does not show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one use `NOT IN()` for the rooms which belongs to whiteboard

```
SELECT DISTINCT room, type
FROM Equipment
WHERE type = 'projector' AND room
 NOT IN (SELECT `room` FROM Equipment WHERE type = 'whiteboard' )
```

Answer (score 0):

A self-join is likely to perform much better than solutions using GROUP BY or subqueries.

```
SELECT e.room, e.type
FROM Equipment AS e
LEFT OUTER JOIN Equipment AS e2
 ON e.room = e2.room AND e2.type = 'whiteboard'
WHERE e.type = 'projector'
 AND e2.type IS NULL;
```

Put an index on `(type,room)` for best results.